# how can i pass integer variable inside where clause in doctrines querybuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I am new on doctrine ORM. I am using codeigniter framework with doctrine and  I get this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given
Filename: Expr/Base.php
Line Number: 92
```

when i try to insert integer variable as parameter in models function

```
public function selectsingle($id){
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('p.name', 'p.email', 'p.subject', 'p.message')
            ->from('PdContact', 'p')
            ->where('p.id', $id);

    $result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    exit;
}
```

how can i pass any integer to where clause.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution after adding `->setParameter("id", $id)` and changing where clause to `->where('p.id = :id')`

```
public function selectsingle($id){
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('p.name', 'p.email', 'p.subject', 'p.message')
            ->from('PdContact', 'p')
            ->where('p.id = :id')
            ->setParameter("id", $id);

    return $result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```